# How could I install Gdal without root

Tags: 14.04

I need to install gdal https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages (or gdal.org), in Linux Ubuntu, but I dont have root privilege. The gdal package is available as ".deb" as well as source files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile the source code

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

And **don't use** `make install` or

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=~/.local
make
make install
```

to install in your home folder.